# How can I change the background color of a textbutton in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to migrate my `FlatButton` to `TextButton`. Since `FlatButtons` are deprecated since I upgraded my flutter version. I'm currently struggling with adapting the background color.

Old button:

```
FlatButton(
        height: height,
        onPressed: onPressed,
        shape: baseButtonBorder,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Text(label, style: TextStyle(color: fontColor, fontWeight: boldLabel ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal)),
      )`
```

New Button:

```
TextButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.red), // <-- Does not work
        child: Text(label, style: TextStyle(color: fontColor, fontWeight: boldLabel ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal)),
      ),
```

The flat button does not have a `color` attribute so I tried to use the `style` attribute and add a `ButtonStyle`. How ever dart says:

`The argument type 'MaterialColor' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MaterialStateProperty<Color>'.`

How can I style my `TextButton` with the color red like I used to do with my `FlatButton`? Do I need to create a `MaterialStateProperty<Color>` with red?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

`backgroundColor` property is `MaterialStateProperty<Color?>` type. You can check in  [Flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle/backgroundColor.html).

So you have to use `MaterialStateProperty` class to apply color. A quick example :

```
TextButton(
    child: Text('test'),
    style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red)),
    onPressed: () {},
),
```

### 2022 Update

Since version 3.0.1, we can use `MaterialStatePropertyAll` as `const`.

So it's a better approach, to use it :

```
TextButton(
    child: Text('test'),
    style: const ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.red),
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
),
```

Comment: May I ask why I have to use `MaterialStateProperty.all` ? Why can't 'I use `Colors.red` directly?

Comment: As documentation says, `bacgroundColor` isn't `Color`type, so you can't use `Colors.red`. You can find more details about `MaterialStateProperty`in Flutter documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateProperty-class.html

Answer (score 37):

For people looking for a clearer and easier way to do this, you can use `TextButton.styleFrom()`. Example:

```
TextButton(
  child: Text('Example'),
  onPressed: () {},
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
)
```

You can customize almost anything you want in styleFrom. This works for other buttons too, like `ElevatedButton` and `OutlinedButton`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way,

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 10, 30, 10),
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Text(""),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

most Easy Way to add a BackGroundColor to `Textbutton`

```
TextButton(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
),
```